# SQL - Transfer Data to different table after INSERT

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to transfer data I have recently inserted into a table to another table in the same database

The insert is working however when I tried to create the query for data transfer I have problems with incorrect syntax and I am unsure how to fix it. I am not even sure if I am using the correct query

I am quite new to this department so I would some help if possible

TLDR: I am trying to write a query that transfers any data I have inserted from one table to another every time

This is my query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tablename]
    INSERT INTO table1 (Name1)
        SELECT Name2
        FROM table2;
        WHERE tbl1_ID = tbl2_ID
```

[image: Here's how it looks like]

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colon after `FROM TABLE2;`. Assuming you want the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy rows from one table to another, just use `insert`, but with no `where` clause (unless you want a subset of the records):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Name1)
    SELECT Name2
    FROM table2;
```

If you want to update a *column* in the first table, then use `update`:

```
update t1
    set name = t2.name2
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.tbl1_ID = t2.tbl2_ID;
```

Comment: I am getting SQL70001 error now that says statement is not recognized in this context

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_tablename]
AS            -- this was missing and is a *mandatory* keyword
    INSERT INTO table1 (Name1)
        SELECT Name2
        FROM table2;   -- <----- if you want the WHERE clause, *DO NOT* put a semicolon here!
        WHERE tbl1_ID = tbl2_ID
```

See [the official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details on the syntax of `CREATE PROCEDURE`